# How to stack frameboxes one next to another filling all available horizontal space

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, fbox

I'm writting a "cheat sheet" where I put a bunch of formulas and ideas inside frameboxes, stacked one after another.

The issue is that paragraph indentation, the framebox separator and the framebox rule cause an overfull \hbox. I can fix the paragraph indendentation with \noindent but I don't know how to fix the other two issues.

Here's a sample that demonstrates the problem. Ideally I would like to keep the sheet as simple as possible. What would be the easiest way to fix this?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=.2in, landscape, showframe=true]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent\fbox{kinematics}
\fbox{$\frac {v^2} 2 - \frac {v_0^2} 2 = \int_{x_0}^x a dx$ (5.8)}
\fbox{curvilinear motion: velocity}
\fbox{$\vec{v} = \vec{u_T} \frac {ds} {dt} = \vec{u_T} v$ (5.23)}
\fbox{curvilinear motion: \emph{constant} acceleration}
\fbox{time to highest point $t = \frac {v_0 \sin \alpha} {g}$ (5.38)}
\fbox{maximum height $h = \frac {v_0^2 \sin^2 \alpha} {2g}$ (5.39)}
\fbox{range $R = \frac {v_0^2 \sin\alpha \cos\alpha} {g} = \frac {v_0^2 \sin 2\alpha} {g} $ (5.40)}
\fbox{tangential and normal (centripetal) acceleration}
\fbox{$\vec{a} = \frac {d\vec{v}} {dt} = \vec{u_T} \frac {dv} {dt} + \frac {d\vec{u_T}} {dt} v$}
\end{document}
```

[image: fbox causing overfull]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=.2in, landscape, showframe=true]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\raggedright
\fbox{kinematics}
\fbox{$\frac {v^2} 2 - \frac {v_0^2} 2 = \int_{x_0}^x a dx$ (5.8)}
\fbox{curvilinear motion: velocity}
\fbox{$\vec{v} = \vec{u_T} \frac {ds} {dt} = \vec{u_T} v$ (5.23)}
\fbox{curvilinear motion: \emph{constant} acceleration}
\fbox{time to highest point $t = \frac {v_0 \sin \alpha} {g}$ (5.38)}
\fbox{maximum height $h = \frac {v_0^2 \sin^2 \alpha} {2g}$ (5.39)}
\fbox{range $R = \frac {v_0^2 \sin\alpha \cos\alpha} {g} = \frac {v_0^2 \sin 2\alpha} {g} $ (5.40)}
\fbox{tangential and normal (centripetal) acceleration}
\fbox{$\vec{a} = \frac {d\vec{v}} {dt} = \vec{u_T} \frac {dv} {dt} + \frac {d\vec{u_T}} {dt} v$}


\bigskip

or

\bigskip



\spaceskip=1sp
\let\oldfbox\fbox
\renewcommand\fbox[1]{\oldfbox{\spaceskip0pt\relax #1}}

\fbox{kinematics}
\fbox{$\frac {v^2} 2 - \frac {v_0^2} 2 = \int_{x_0}^x a dx$ (5.8)}
\fbox{curvilinear motion: velocity}
\fbox{$\vec{v} = \vec{u_T} \frac {ds} {dt} = \vec{u_T} v$ (5.23)}
\fbox{curvilinear motion: \emph{constant} acceleration}
\fbox{time to highest point $t = \frac {v_0 \sin \alpha} {g}$ (5.38)}
\fbox{maximum height $h = \frac {v_0^2 \sin^2 \alpha} {2g}$ (5.39)}
\fbox{range $R = \frac {v_0^2 \sin\alpha \cos\alpha} {g} = \frac {v_0^2 \sin 2\alpha} {g} $ (5.40)}
\fbox{tangential and normal (centripetal) acceleration}
\fbox{$\vec{a} = \frac {d\vec{v}} {dt} = \vec{u_T} \frac {dv} {dt} + \frac {d\vec{u_T}} {dt} v$}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a manual paragraph break and fom `\hfill` commands you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[margin=.2in, landscape, showframe=true]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\fbox{kinematics}\hfill
\fbox{$\frac {v^2} 2 - \frac {v_0^2} 2 = \int_{x_0}^x a dx$ (5.8)}\hfill
\fbox{curvilinear motion: velocity}\hfill
\fbox{$\vec{v} = \vec{u_T} \frac {ds} {dt} = \vec{u_T} v$ (5.23)}\hfill
\fbox{curvilinear motion: \emph{constant} acceleration}\hfill
\fbox{time to highest point $t = \frac {v_0 \sin \alpha} {g}$ (5.38)}

\fbox{maximum height $h = \frac {v_0^2 \sin^2 \alpha} {2g}$ (5.39)}
\fbox{range $R = \frac {v_0^2 \sin\alpha \cos\alpha} {g} = \frac {v_0^2 \sin 2\alpha} {g} $ (5.40)}
\fbox{tangential and normal (centripetal) acceleration}
\fbox{$\vec{a} = \frac {d\vec{v}} {dt} = \vec{u_T} \frac {dv} {dt} + \frac {d\vec{u_T}} {dt} v$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a simpler syntax. This inserts a zero skip between every two boxes, so to have a feasible break point. With `\raggedright` we finally get the desired output.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=.2in, landscape, showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\boxes}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl { \fbox{\l_tmpa_tl}\hspace{0pt} }
  \par
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\raggedright

\boxes{
kinematics \\
$\frac {v^2} 2 - \frac {v_0^2} 2 = \int_{x_0}^x a dx$ (5.8) \\
curvilinear motion: velocity \\
$\vec{v} = \vec{u_T} \frac {ds} {dt} = \vec{u_T} v$ (5.23) \\
curvilinear motion: \emph{constant} acceleration \\
time to highest point $t = \frac {v_0 \sin \alpha} {g}$ (5.38) \\
maximum height $h = \frac {v_0^2 \sin^2 \alpha} {2g}$ (5.39) \\
range $R = \frac {v_0^2 \sin\alpha \cos\alpha} {g} = \frac {v_0^2 \sin 2\alpha} {g} $ (5.40) \\
tangential and normal (centripetal) acceleration \\
$\vec{a} = \frac {d\vec{v}} {dt} = \vec{u_T} \frac {dv} {dt} + \frac {d\vec{u_T}} {dt} v$
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also get justification:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\boxes}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \noindent
  \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl { \fbox{\l_tmpa_tl}\hspace{0pt plus 0.01fil} }
  \par
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

but this is more likely to produce overfull lines.